# Output variable value from variable within a variable

Tags: powershell

Im having trouble outputting the value of a variable name that is in a variable.
I have one array that contains the name of several other arrays like this:

```
>$arrayx1
array00
array01
array02
array03
array10
array11
array12
array13
```

Each of those arrays have their own value, I want to output that value to a file in a loop. I got the loop and everything else working, except it outputs the name of the arrays and not the arrays value.

```
$outnr1 = 0
$outnr2 = 0
$null | out-file $path
foreach ($nr3 in $arrayx1) {
    $output = $arrayx1[$outnr2]
    echo "$($output)" | out-file $path -encoding Unicode -append
    $outnr2 = $outnr2 + 1
    if ($outnr2 -gt 3) {
        $outnr1 = $outnr1 + 1
        }
    }
```

The file ends up looking like $arrayx1

Comment: To get variable by name you should use `Get-Variable` cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable variables (like `$$Name` in PHP) aren't supported in PowerShell.

Instead, as [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766826/output-variable-value-from-variable-within-a-variable/34768753#comment57280917_34766826), you should use [`Get-Variable`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849899.aspx) to retrieve the value of the a variable you have the name of:

```
foreach($varName in $arrayx1)
{
    $var = Get-Variable -Name $varName -ValueOnly
    $var | Out-File $path -Encoding Unicode -Append
}
```

---

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish with the `$outnr1` and `$outnr2` variables in your original example, but if you want to limit the output to just the first 3 items in `$arrayx1`, use `Select-Object -First`:

```
foreach($varName in $arrayx1 | Select-Object -First 3)
{
    $var = Get-Variable -Name $varName -ValueOnly
    $var | Out-File $path -Encoding Unicode -Append
}
```

or the range operator:

```
foreach($varName in $arrayx1[0..2])
{
    $var = Get-Variable -Name $varName -ValueOnly
    $var | Out-File $path -Encoding Unicode -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!
Im going to use the $outnr1 and $outnr2 to set line breaks in the file that is being written to.